# Create an app to get public data from facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create an application that gets public information from different users or pages but using the same app access token. Is that possible or is the app access token limited to getting data from the user registering the application? Note that this is without a human user logging in first.

Comment: You can get info about fully public pages, but when it comes to user profiles, what you get access to without the user's prior explicit consent is extremely limited.